Unity Raycast doesn't recognize collision
I'm trying to get an interaction system done in Unity for my project using raycast to measure the distance between player and object to interact with. Using both DrawLine and DrawRay it looks like the raycast collide with the object, but the conditions are not reached.


There are 3 scripts
Player script
private void Update()
{
    InteractionRay();
}

void InteractionRay()
{
    Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    RaycastHit hit;

    bool hitSomething = false;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, interactionRange))
    {
        Iinteractable interactable = hit.collider.GetComponent<Iinteractable>();

        if (interactable != null)
        {
            hitSomething = true;
            interactionText.text = interactable.GetDescription();

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.N))
            {
                interactable.Interact();
            }
        }
    }
    interactionUI.SetActive(hitSomething);
    //Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin,interactionRange* ray.direction, Color.green);
    Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, hit.point, Color.red);
}

interface script
public interface Iinteractable
{
    void Interact();
    string GetDescription();
}

object script
public class Test : MonoBehaviour, Iinteractable
{

    public string GetDescription()
    {
        return "Press";
    }

    public void Interact()
    {
        Debug.Log("Did Hit");
    }
}

I tried checking both settings in Physics -> GameObject but can't figure it out.
I'd like to mention that I'm very newbie into programming and the code is basically a copy paste from a tutorial with small adaptations to my case. The scripts have been assigned properly on character and object to interact with.

Have you tried Debugging your code? Are you sure you are within the range? Are you sure your hitting the right thing? Are you sure the component is attached?
